# R boxplot: change bar width + space with

Tags: r, visualization, boxplot, rdata

I need some help designing my R graphs. I created this boxplot here and everything is correct but I trouble to understand why there are differences in the bar width and space between them. There is nothing in the data which could create this (it's just some rows of matrices).
I tried changing the arguments varwith, width/length, space and boxwex. The different boxwex values will change the bar width to some degree but not the variation of it.

I would be glad if some has an idea here.

P.S.: Sorry, I'm new here so I can't upload the graph itself.

```
dput(datesALL)
structure(c(-130L, -70L, -130L, -70L, -130L, -70L, -130L, -70L, 
-130L, -70L, -120L, -75L, -100L, -75L, -100L, -50L, -100L, -50L, 
-100L, -50L, -100L, -50L, -100L, -75L, -100L, -35L, -90L, -80L, 
-90L, -50L, -90L, -50L, -90L, -50L, -90L, -50L, -90L, -50L, -90L, 
-50L, -90L, -50L, -90L, -50L, -90L, -80L, -90L, -50L, -90L, -50L, 
-89L, -50L, -89L, -50L, -80L, -58L, -80L, -50L, -80L, -65L, -80L, 
-50L, -80L, -50L, -80L, -50L, -80L, -50L, -80L, -50L, -80L, -50L, 
-80L, -50L, -80L, -50L, -80L, -50L, -80L, -50L, -80L, -50L, -80L, 
-50L, -80L, -50L, -75L, -60L, -75L, -50L, -75L, -50L, -75L, -50L, 
-75L, -60L, -75L, -60L, -75L, -50L, -75L, -50L, -75L, -50L, -75L, 
-50L, -75L, -50L, -75L, -50L, -75L, -50L, -75L, -50L, -75L, -50L, 
-75L, -60L, -36L, -30L, 14L, 37L, 25L, 100L, 50L, 100L, 79L, 
81L, -90L, -50L, -90L, -50L, 0L, 25L, -50L, 0L, 50L, 100L, 50L, 
79L, 54L, 68L, 66L, 68L, -49L, -41L, -30L, -12L, -30L, -12L, 
0L, 15L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 25L, 10L, 30L, 25L, 50L, 
42L, 48L, 69L, 79L), .Dim = c(2L, 84L), .Dimnames = list(c("date_min", 
"date_max"), NULL))

colors = c(rep("powderblue",64),rep("khaki",3),rep("darkolivegreen2",5),rep("mistyrose",12))
medcolors = c(rep("powderblue",64),rep("khaki",3),rep("darkolivegreen2",5),rep("mistyrose",12))

boxplot(datesALL, horizontal=TRUE, outline=FALSE, boxwex=0.5,  
yaxt="n", col=colors, medcol=medcolors, 
main="..", 
xlab="..", ylab="")
```

Comment: can you edit your question to add the copy and paste of `dput(datesALL)`. It's a more "shareable" format than the print output you've included already

Comment: that's shorter, you're right. Thx.

Comment: it's easy for me (and others) to copy and past into an actual R object too! That's the real motivation. Welcome to SO!

Comment: The sizing and spacing look consistent to me, not sure if there is specific place you are looking, you could always upload an annotated image to Imgur (or other hosting) place and put a link in your question

Comment: ![Boxplot](https://i.imgur.com/7iRlTG0.png)
Here's my boxplot. The bar width is smaller on some bars.